# JFormattedTextField issues

Tags: java, swing, formatter, jformattedtextfield

[image] [image]

1) how can I set Cursor to 0 possition without using Caret or Focus wrapped into invokeLater() (confortly can be solved by using @camickr [Formatted Text Field Tips](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/formatted-text-field-tips/)), is there somebody who knows another way

[image] [image]

2) `How to reset Formatter` sometimes (by raising Focus by TAB from keyboard), reset doesn't works and on focusLost (empty field) Formatter returns/reincarnated chars or String back (last know before setText("");),

Note: know code or following code `is only this way`, about how to reset Formatter from OTN, but their terrible search rulles ...., only code (question or answer by Jeanette???)

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

public class FormattedNull {

    private JFormattedTextField field;
    private JButton focusButton;

    private JComponent createContent() {
        JComponent content = new JPanel();
        field = new JFormattedTextField(new Integer(55));
        field.setColumns(20);
        field.addPropertyChangeListener(getPropertyChangeListener());
        field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(getDocumentListener());
        content.add(field);
        focusButton = new JButton("just something focusable");
        focusButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                field.setValue(0);
                field.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });
        content.add(focusButton);
        return content;
    }

    protected void maybeCommitEdit(Document document) {
        try {
            field.commitEdit();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // uncomment to map empty string to null
            if (field.getText().length() == 0) {
                field.setValue(null);
            }
        }
    }

    /*public void commitEdit() throws ParseException {
    if(allowsNull() && isBlank()) {
    setValue(null);
    }
    else {
    super.commitEdit();
    }
    }*/
    private PropertyChangeListener getPropertyChangeListener() {
        PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeListener = new PropertyChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if ("value".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                    matchValueChanged(evt.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        };
        return propertyChangeListener;
    }

    protected void matchValueChanged(Object value) {
        System.out.println("got new value: " + value);
    }

    private DocumentListener getDocumentListener() {
        DocumentListener documentListener = new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                maybeCommitEdit(e.getDocument());
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                maybeCommitEdit(e.getDocument());
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            }
        };
        return documentListener;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new FormattedNull().createContent());
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

attached images are based on my sscce

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

public class TestTest {

    private JFormattedTextField myFormattedField1 = new JFormattedTextField(createFormatter("AAAAAAAAAAAA"));
    private JFormattedTextField myFormattedField2 = new JFormattedTextField(createFormatter("AAAAAAAAAAAA"));
    private JFormattedTextField myFormattedField3 = new JFormattedTextField(createFormatter("AAAAAAAAAAAA"));
    private JFormattedTextField myFormattedField4 = new JFormattedTextField(createFormatter("AAAAAAAAAAAA"));
    private JButton jb = new JButton("Reset to Default");
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Text Test");

    public TestTest() {
        myFormattedField1.setText("ABCDEFGHIJKL");
        myFormattedField2.setText("ABCDEFGHIJKL");
        myFormattedField3.setText("ABCDEFGHIJKL");
        myFormattedField4.setText("ABCDEFGHIJKL");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 0));
        frame.add(jb);
        frame.add(myFormattedField1);
        frame.add(myFormattedField2);
        frame.add(myFormattedField3);
        frame.add(myFormattedField4);
        jb.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                myFormattedField1.setText("");
                myFormattedField2.setText("");
                myFormattedField3.setText("");
                myFormattedField4.setText("");
            }
        });
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestTest textTest = new TestTest();
    }

    protected MaskFormatter createFormatter(String s) {
        MaskFormatter formatter = null;
        try {
            formatter = new MaskFormatter(s);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException exc) {
            System.err.println("formatter is bad: " + exc.getMessage());
        }
        return formatter;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) why? 2) empty string is an invalid entry, so the field reverts to the mask itself (set a placeHolderChar to see, spaces are invisible :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. On Mac OS, the default behavior of the UI delegate, `com.apple.laf.AquaTextFieldF`, is similar to [`CaretPositionListener`](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/formatted-text-field-tips/):

   - <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>: place the caret at the beginning of the field.
   - Click: briefly place the caret at the beginning of the field and then move it to the click point.

   IMO, the [`CaretPositionListener`](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/formatted-text-field-tips/) does the latter much more smoothly.
2. The default behavior of [`JFormattedTextField`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) on focus lost is `COMMIT_OR_REVERT`. In the example below, <kbd>Tab</kbd> though the first, invalid field to see the effect. The formatter can neither commit nor revert to the invalid value, so it substitutes `MASK.length()` spaces. This value is valid, if a little obscure.

Addendum: I've updated the code below to allow changing the [`setFocusLostBehavior()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html#setFocusLostBehavior%28int%29).

Code:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378821 */
public class TrashTest {

    private static final String MASK = "########";
    private static final String DEFAULT = "01234567";
    private static final String BOGUS = "0123456";
    private JFormattedTextField jtf1 = createField();
    private JFormattedTextField jtf2 = createField();
    private JFormattedTextField jtf3 = createField();
    private JFormattedTextField jtf4 = createField();
    private JButton reset = new JButton("Reset to Default");
    private JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Text Test");

    public TrashTest() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        frame.add(reset);
        frame.add(jtf1);
        frame.add(jtf2);
        frame.add(jtf3);
        frame.add(jtf4);
        frame.add(combo);
        this.initFields();
        reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                initFields();
            }
        });
        for (Edit e : Edit.values()) {
            combo.addItem(e);
        }
        combo.setSelectedIndex(jtf1.getFocusLostBehavior());
        combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Edit current = (Edit) combo.getSelectedItem();
                jtf1.setFocusLostBehavior(current.value);
            }
        });
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initFields() {
        jtf1.setText(BOGUS);
        jtf2.setText(DEFAULT);
        jtf3.setText(DEFAULT);
        jtf4.setText(DEFAULT);
    }

    protected JFormattedTextField createField() {
        MaskFormatter formatter = null;
        try {
            formatter = new MaskFormatter(MASK);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
        JFormattedTextField jtf = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        return jtf;
    }

    enum Edit {

        COMMIT(JFormattedTextField.COMMIT),
        COMMIT_OR_REVERT(JFormattedTextField.COMMIT_OR_REVERT),
        REVERT(JFormattedTextField.REVERT),
        PERSIST(JFormattedTextField.PERSIST);
        private int value;

        private Edit(int n) {
            this.value = n;
        }

        public static Edit getEnum(int n) {
            for (Edit e : Edit.values()) {
                if (e.value == n) {
                    return e;
                }
            }
            return Edit.COMMIT_OR_REVERT;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TrashTest textTest = new TrashTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is rather empirical; I'd welcome any corrections or a better answer.

Comment: For reference, I've updated the code to allow selecting the focus-lost setting.

Comment: thanks I don't really understood how excelent ans correctly works your code, thanks for another lesson

Comment: Sorry it's not more constructive. The API says `COMMIT_OR_REVERT` is the default; I intended `getEnum()` as a check, but it's superfluous.