# Java : JFormattedTextField saving numbers

Tags: java, swing, number-formatting, jformattedtextfield

In my application I want to input numbers (amounts) to a specific limit, and hence have used JFormattedTextField. Limit like "12345678.99" i.e. 8 digits before "." and 2 after "." or so on. This is my implementation code, but it doesn't result as expected.

```
    startBalTxt.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter(new java.text.DecimalFormat("########.##"))));
    startBalTxt.setText(resourceMap.getString("startBalTxt.text")); // NOI18N
    startBalTxt.setFont(Utility.getTextFont());
    startBalTxt.setName("startBalTxt"); // NOI18N
```

---

```
  INPUT                RESULT  
"12345678905.99"   => "12345678906"      ==> Should give "12345678.99" or "12345679.99"
"12345678.555"     => "12345678.56"      ==> CORRECT
"1234567890123456" => "1234567890123456" ==> Absolutely wrong in all aspects
```

Where am I going wrong ? And how to make this working as I am expecting it.

**UPDATIONS AS PER SUGGESTED by StanislavL :**

```
    numberFormat = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance();
    numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    numberFormat.setMaximumIntegerDigits(8);
    numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
    numberFormat.setMinimumIntegerDigits(2);

    nfr = new NumberFormatter(numberFormat);

    initComponents();
    myParent = parent;
    this.startBalTxt.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(nfr));

    Results ->  4562147896.45  == > 62,147,896.45
```

Its obeying the limit that's true, but its eliminating previous numbers instead of later. I mean in 4562147896.45 instead of "45" "96" shouldn't be eliminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

even `JFormattedTextField` implements `DecimalFormat` and `NumberFormat`, better would be use `DocumentListener`,

1) its not good jumping betweens `Big Figures` by using `DecimalFormat` or `NumberFormat` simple `User-non-Acceptable` by implements setMinimum() and setMaximum()

2) `JTextComponents` by default implements insert the text, then any workaround is so `User-non-Acceptable` by implements`JFormattedTextField` with `DecimalFormat` or`NumberFormat` by implements setMinimum() and setMaximum()

3) its very confortable je use `DocumentListener` allows add any amount, but with highlighting out-off range

4) or use `JSpinner` with `SpinnerNumberModel`, there is posible to set Formatter as for Number Instance

example for `InternationalFormatter` and `DocumentListener` together

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
import java.math.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.InternationalFormatter;

public class DocumentListenerAdapter {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("AbstractTextField Test");
        final JFormattedTextField textField1 = new JFormattedTextField(new Float(10.01));
        textField1.setFormatterFactory(new AbstractFormatterFactory() {

            @Override
            public AbstractFormatter getFormatter(JFormattedTextField tf) {
                NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
                format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
                format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
                format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                InternationalFormatter formatter = new InternationalFormatter(format);
                formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
                formatter.setMinimum(0.0);
                formatter.setMaximum(1000.00);
                return formatter;
            }
        });
        final Map attributes = (new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 16)).getAttributes();
        attributes.put(TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH, TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH_ON);
        final JFormattedTextField textField2 = new JFormattedTextField(new Float(10.01));
        textField2.setFormatterFactory(new AbstractFormatterFactory() {

            @Override
            public AbstractFormatter getFormatter(JFormattedTextField tf) {
                NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
                format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
                format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
                format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                InternationalFormatter formatter = new InternationalFormatter(format);
                formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
                //formatter.setMinimum(0.0);
                //formatter.setMaximum(1000.00);
                return formatter;
            }
        });
        textField2.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
                printIt(documentEvent);
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
                printIt(documentEvent);
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
                printIt(documentEvent);
            }

            private void printIt(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
                DocumentEvent.EventType type = documentEvent.getType();
                double t1a1 = (((Number) textField2.getValue()).doubleValue());
                if (t1a1 > 1000) {
                    Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textField2.setFont(new Font(attributes));
                            textField2.setForeground(Color.red);
                        }
                    };
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);
                } else {
                    Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textField2.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 16));
                            textField2.setForeground(Color.black);
                        }
                    };
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);
                }
            }
        });
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(textField1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(textField2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }

    private DocumentListenerAdapter() {
    }
}
```

Comment: excellent example. I didn't get your 1st point - why User-non-accepteble ? While surfing for solution for the above I read many times developers say its not good to use DocumentListener for such tasks instead one should use formatter only. One reason I could find is DocumentListenr shows results after we have moved from that textfield whereas formatter will show on spot only. Can you pour some light on this.

Comment: @Tvd I forgot to add setMinimum() and setMaximum() to my answer, there no going about developers like or wharever, is about user_freindyl, really moving inside alloved possitions is terrible,

Comment: If I add setMinimum & setMaximum to textfield2's formatter, then printIt() of DocumentListener is never active. Even if I try to do Copy-Paste then also the formatter only takes care and doesn't allow to paste invalid data. If I got to implement formatter & DocumentListener (as done for textfield2) and formatter only looks up mostly then where & when DocumentListener comes under picture ??

Comment: right, but problems cames when you touched limits with Focus or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378821/jformattedtextfield-issues

Comment: Right @mKorbel. Thanks for clarifications. And yes, I have another formattedtextField where I have set Mask and in that field I see what you are saying in the above link. I tried to add the DocumentListner as shown in your query. But couldn't get any way to implement trashTest's solution wher I have just JFT's. Can you show some guideline. Thanks a lot. –

Comment: FocusListener helped me do my job. Added focusGained and in SwingUtilities.invokeLater() checked if (ftf.getValue() == null) then I set its value and text to "". This puts the caret sign on 0th element. This works with mouse and Tab, Shift-Tab. I had problem with mouse click only.

Answer (score 7):

Pass [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) to the `JFormattedTextField` constructor. It has following methods

```
setMaximumIntegerDigits
setMinimumIntegerDigits
setMaximumFractionDigits
setMinimumFractionDigits
```

Comment: Actually, I am using NetBeans. Can't modify the constructor. Got to use FormatFactory only to set it. Added above code and also shwn the results in thee.

Comment: @Tvd if a tool stands in your way, don't use it. At least _completely_ learn all its possibilities (pretty sure - as in guessing around, never use it myself - it supports all constructors)

Comment: Can that elimination of digits be handed out - as mentioned in the question at bottom.

Comment: How can I restrict integer digits to only 8 - after 8 digits it beeps or doesn't allow input any such sort of indication for the user ????