# setMinimumFractionDigits(..) detail. NumberFormat class

Tags: java, api, doc, number-formatting

Directly from this [java api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMinimumFractionDigits%28int%29)

> **setMinimumFractionDigits**
>
> ```
> public void setMinimumFractionDigits(int newValue)
> ```
>
> *Sets the minimum number of digits allowed in the fraction portion of a
>   number. minimumFractionDigits must be <= maximumFractionDigits. If the
>   new value for minimumFractionDigits exceeds the current value of
>   maximumFractionDigits, then maximumIntegerDigits will also be set to
>   the new value.*

What is the concern of `maximumIntegerDigits` with `mimimumFractionDigits` as specified in the above statement? (Exactly the following bit: "***then maximumIntegerDigits will also be set to the new value***"

Comment: [you can see here, for example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8582656/714968)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that if you are setting the minimum to be a value larger than the maximum, that the maximum will be set to the minimum number.  This way no constraint is broken.  It would be strange to have a minimum larger than the maximum.

Example:

```
num.setMaximumFractionDigits(5);
num.setMinimumFractionDigits(8);
// the maximum is automatically set to 8
```

The line you specified is actually a javadoc typo, they meant maximiumFractionDigit, from OpenJDK

```
public void setMinimumFractionDigits(int newValue) {
    minimumFractionDigits = Math.max(0,newValue);
    if (maximumFractionDigits < minimumFractionDigits) {
        maximumFractionDigits = minimumFractionDigits;
    }
}
```

Comment: They are referring to maximumIntegerDigits at the end.. not to maximumFractionDigits. That is what is not logic.

Comment: @Rollerball: Check my edit, you have found a typo in the javadoc,  the code itself sets maximumFractionDigit.