# Clearing contents of JFormattedTextField not working?

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

1. I have a `JFormattedTextField` which accepts number of 8 digits only, but when I try to clear the textfield with backspace button it doesnt delete first character of number (same behavior with delete button too), I have to presee Esc key to delete this character each time.

   ```
   NumberFormat intFormat = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
   intFormat.setGroupingUsed(false);
   NumberFormatter numberFormatter = new NumberFormatter(intFormat);
   numberFormatter.setValueClass(Integer.class); 
   numberFormatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
   numberFormatter.setMinimum(0);
   numberFormatter.setMaximum(99999999);

   releaseNoTextField = new JFormattedTextField(numberFormatter);
   ```

what's the problem here ?

2. Also clearing this textfield with `releaseNoTextField.setText("")` is not working, is there another way to do this ?

Comment: *"Also clearing this textfield with releaseNoTextField.setText("") is not working, is there another way to do this ?"* - Have you tried `setValue(null)`?

Comment: What means `is not working`?

Comment: I "think" it's a requirement between the `JFormattedTextField`, `NumberFormatter` and `NumberFormat` that `""` is not a valid number, therefore it's rejecting your attempt to remove the last character.  This requirement is been enforced by `numberFormatter.setAllowsInvalid`.  If you don't really care about the format of the value, but simply restricting the user's input, you could use a `JTextField` and `DocumentFilter`

Comment: @MadProgrammer  is there any way I can prompt the error after user leaves the field along with clearing the text ?

Comment: If you're using `setAllowsInvalid(true)`, then the field should be reset after the user leaves the field. normally, I'd use an `InputVerifier`, but I'm not sure that would suitable for a `JFormattedTextField`

Comment: Actually, I lie, apparently you can use a `InputVerifer`, have a look at the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) for an example

Comment: @user3462473 [for more infor... read](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7378821/714968)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have a JFormattedTextField which accepts number of 8 digits only, but when I try to clear the textfield with backspace button it doesnt delete first character of number (same behavior with delete button too), I have to presee Esc key to delete this character each time.

This is a restriction been applied by `numberFormatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);` which sees a blank `String` (`""`) as not been a valid numerical value.  If you use `numberFormatter.setAllowsInvalid(true);` you can remove all the characters, but you can also enter any value you like.

The field will be validated AFTER the user leaves the field though.

If you don't care about the value been formatted (`12, 345, 678`), then you could use a `DocumentFilter` applied to a plain `JTextField` an implement the logic you require within it.  See [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](https://www.javatips.net/api/javax.swing.text.documentfilter) for more details.

> Also clearing this textfield with releaseNoTextField.setText("") is not working, is there another way to do this ?

You should (always) be using `setValue` for `JFormattedTextField` and you should true `setValue(null)` to clear the field

Comment: Your link to DocumentFilter Examples appears broken

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yea, welcome to the internet 

Answer (score 0):

What if you don't want to allow invalid input but the empty textfield shall be still allowed ? Just overwrite the stringToValue()-method from the NumberFormatter

```
NumberFormat intFormat = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
intFormat.setGroupingUsed(false);
NumberFormatter numberFormatter = new NumberFormatter(intFormat){
    @Override
    public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
        if (text.length() == 0)
            return null;
        return super.stringToValue(text);
    }
};
numberFormatter.setValueClass(Integer.class); 
numberFormatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
numberFormatter.setMinimum(0);
numberFormatter.setMaximum(99999999);
```

Answer (score -1):

`releaseNoTextField.setFocusLostBehavior(javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.COMMIT);`